# Open a Sequel Pro connection from command line

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I have a database on a SaaS platform (Pantheon), and the connection string changes frequently (multiple times per day). This makes Sequel Pro favorites pretty useless.

I can easily fetch the new connection string from Terminal, and I can launch Sequel Pro from Terminal, but I can't figure out how to feed the connection string to Sequel Pro properly.

I've read through [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/issues/detail?id=206), but just cannot figure out the proper syntax.

How can I make it work? Any other ideas about how to achieve similar?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could write the changes to your Sequel Pro **Favourites.plist** -file and then start the program with **--favorite** (--favorite=site1 etc.) parameter.

Favourites.plist is normal text file in xml form and can be edited with a script etc.

In Mac OS X the favourites file is at **~/Library/Application Support/Sequel Pro/Data/Favourites.plist**

This won't work if your password changes also as it's stored OS X Keychain. (Not sure where passwords are in Windows, sorry)

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing: https://gist.github.com/aaronbauman/f50cc691eb3ed60a358c